# Application of functions and Kleisli arrows

Tags: haskell, typeclass, kleisli

`(.)` and `(<=<)` are quite similar:

```
(.)   ::            (b ->   c) -> (a ->   b) -> (a ->   c)
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)
```

and are available as a method in the `Category` type class (`(->)` and `Kleisli` instances):

```
(<<<) :: (Category f) => f b c -> f a b -> f a c
```

`($)` and `(=<<)` are also quite similar:

```
($)   ::            (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Is there a type class that abstracts over these application functions?

Comment: With suitable extensions and imports, `($) :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> b; ($) = coerce ((=<<) @Identity @a @b)` is a perfectly acceptable definition of `($)`. So in some sense, `Monad` already *is* the class that abstracts over these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples are arrow mappings of functors (not `Functors`, but functors in the broader categorical sense), just like `fmap` is the arrow mapping of a `Functor`. `(=<<)`, for instance, is the arrow mapping of a functor from `Kleisli m` to `(->)` for some monad `m`. An appropriate generalisation, then, is one that accounts for functors between different categories. [`Control.Categorical.Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Categorical-Functor.html) provides that:

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Functor f r t | f r -> t, f t -> r where
  fmap :: r a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

Armed with that, you would be able to write an instance in the spirit of:

```
-- `(.)` is plain old Prelude `(.)`, and not the generalised `Category` one.
instance Monad m => Functor m (Kleisli m) (->) where
    fmap = (=<<) . runKleisli
```

Or, for something you can actually run:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Arrow (Kleisli(..))
import qualified Control.Categorical.Functor as F

newtype BindF m a = BindF { runBindF :: m a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, Show)

instance Monad m => F.Functor (BindF m) (Kleisli (BindF m)) (->) where
    fmap = (=<<) . runKleisli
```

```
GHCi> F.fmap (Kleisli (BindF . replicate 2)) (BindF [1,2,3])
BindF {runBindF = [1,1,2,2,3,3]}
```

A similar instance might be written, for instance, for `(<*>)`, in terms of the [`Static`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.1/docs/Data-Semigroupoid-Static.html) category. As for `($)`, it is the arrow mapping of the identity functor in `(->)`, and so it is merely `fmap` for `Identity` sans the `Identity` wrapper (cf. Daniel Wagner's comment to the question).

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel's comment says, `(=<<)` already encompasses `($)`. There is already a newtype (similar to how there is a `Kleisli` newtype for `a -> m b` for `Category`) for `a` called [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html), which has a `Monad` instance such that

```
f $ x
```

corresponds to

```
Identity . f =<< Identity x
```

---

While there are subcomponents that are reused in `(.)` and `(<=<)` (namely `a -> b` in the former and `a -> m b` in the latter) which can be abstracted out to a typeclass for a type constructor `a :: * -> * -> *` (which turns out to be `Category`), the largest such subcomponent in `($)` and `(=<<)` is just `a` in the former and `m a` in the latter.